# Converting a tbl_df to a ts

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to convert a tbl_df to a ts time-series in R. Below is the head() of my data frame:

```
    head(Investment)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  TIME_PERIOD GPDI_Chained LogGPDI CorpTaxX Baseline_Uncertainty  gGDP PCE_Defl ofPagesFedReg logabsgGDP
  <chr>              <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>                <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>
1 1985 Q1            1122.    3.05     20.2                 112.   3.9     1.82         50502      0.591
2 1985 Q2            1141.    3.06     19.8                 119.   3.6     1.75         50502      0.556
3 1985 Q3            1134.    3.05     20.6                 127.   6.2     1.77         50502      0.792
4 1985 Q4            1176.    3.07     20.1                 124.   3       1.82         50502      0.477
5 1986 Q1            1175.    3.07     23.8                 159.   3.8     1.60         44812      0.580
6 1986 Q2            1155.    3.06     24.3                 135.   1.8     1.12         44812      0.255
```

I have tried to coerce the Tibble into a ts by using the following:

```
> DF <- read.table("file_path", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=NULL)
> InvestmentTS<-as.ts(DF)
```

which yields:

```
> head(InvestmentTS)
     TIME_PERIOD GPDI_Chained  LogGPDI CorpTaxX Baseline_Uncertainty gGDP PCE_Defl ofPagesFedReg logabsgGDP
[1,]           1       1122.3 3.050109 20.23836             112.1454  3.9    1.818         50502  0.5910646
[2,]           2       1141.4 3.057438 19.78908             118.5357  3.6    1.751         50502  0.5563025
[3,]           3       1133.7 3.054498 20.64556             127.1788  6.2    1.770         50502  0.7923917
[4,]           4       1175.5 3.070223 20.05952             123.7795  3.0    1.825         50502  0.4771213
[5,]           5       1175.1 3.070075 23.80535             158.5329  3.8    1.597         44812  0.5797836
[6,]           6       1154.6 3.062432 24.26877             135.1720  1.8    1.115         44812  0.2552725
```

The problem here is that I have lost my "year-quarter" column (`TIME_PERIOD`).
Now I have also tried to convert the TIME_PERIOD column into a yearqtr using:

```
quarter<-c("1985-1" , ... , "2018-3")
> as.yearqtr(format(quarter), "%Y-%q")
```

Which is successful, however, I don't know how to implement this into the ts so that the TIME_PERIOD column has the year_quarter dates instead of ordinal numbers.

Would someone be able to help explain how to convert the tbl_df to ts so that it shows the dates from the TIME_PERIOD column?

I apologize in advance if this has been answered elsewhere or if its an overly simple answer, I am just learning R and only need this data-frame to be ts so I can run some diagnostic tests for my time-series regression model which apparently require data to be ts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For what it's worth, `as.ts` specifies that data.frames are always converted to numeric matrices, so any type information will necessarily be lost. The `zoo` or `tsibble` packages may provide more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. For the first line: I don't know why the code is yielding "A Tibble" instead of data.frame, perhaps that's part of the problem?
And yes I misspoke, I meant "year-quarter column" not row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help you.

```
tbl$TIME_PERIOD <- as.yearqtr(tbl$TIME_PERIOD, format = "%Y Q%q")
ts(tbl[,-1], start = as.yearmon(tbl$TIME_PERIOD[1]), frequency = 4)
```

Sample data:

```
tbl <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = "|", text = "
TIME_PERIOD|GPDI_Chained|LogGPDI|CorpTaxX|Baseline_Uncertainty|gGDP|PCE_Defl|ofPagesFedReg|logabsgGDP
1985 Q1|1122.|3.05|20.2|112.|3.9|1.82|50502|0.591
1985 Q2|1141.|3.06|19.8|119.|3.6|1.75|50502|0.556
1985 Q3|1134.|3.05|20.6|127.|6.2|1.77|50502|0.792
1985 Q4|1176.|3.07|20.1|124.|3|1.82|50502|0.477
1986 Q1|1175.|3.07|23.8|159.|3.8|1.60|44812|0.580")
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a zoo object `z` and then to `ts`:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(tbl, FUN = as.yearqtr)
as.ts(z)
```

giving:

```
        GPDI_Chained LogGPDI CorpTaxX Baseline_Uncertainty gGDP PCE_Defl ofPagesFedReg logabsgGDP
1985 Q1         1122    3.05     20.2                  112  3.9     1.82         50502      0.591
1985 Q2         1141    3.06     19.8                  119  3.6     1.75         50502      0.556
1985 Q3         1134    3.05     20.6                  127  6.2     1.77         50502      0.792
1985 Q4         1176    3.07     20.1                  124  3.0     1.82         50502      0.477
1986 Q1         1175    3.07     23.8                  159  3.8     1.60         44812      0.580
```

### Note

```
tbl <- 
structure(list(TIME_PERIOD = structure(1:5, .Label = c("1985 Q1", 
"1985 Q2", "1985 Q3", "1985 Q4", "1986 Q1"), class = "factor"), 
    GPDI_Chained = c(1122, 1141, 1134, 1176, 1175), LogGPDI = c(3.05, 
    3.06, 3.05, 3.07, 3.07), CorpTaxX = c(20.2, 19.8, 20.6, 20.1, 
    23.8), Baseline_Uncertainty = c(112, 119, 127, 124, 159), 
    gGDP = c(3.9, 3.6, 6.2, 3, 3.8), PCE_Defl = c(1.82, 1.75, 
    1.77, 1.82, 1.6), ofPagesFedReg = c(50502L, 50502L, 50502L, 
    50502L, 44812L), logabsgGDP = c(0.591, 0.556, 0.792, 0.477, 
    0.58)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

An update: I highly recommend the new [tidyverts](https://tidyverts.org/) packages for integrating time series into tidyverse-style workflows:

From the [Hyndsight](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tsibbles/) blog by Rob Hyndman,
29 August 2019:

> **Tidy time series data using tsibbles**

> There is a new suite of packages for tidy time series analysis, that
> integrates easily into the tidyverse way of working. We call these the
> tidyverts packages, and they are available at [tidyverts.org](https://tidyverts.org/). Much of
> the work on these packages has been done by Earo Wang and Mitchell
> O’Hara-Wild.
>
> The first of the packages to make it to CRAN was tsibble, providing
> the data infrastructure for tidy temporal data with wrangling tools. A
> tsibble (where “ts” is pronounced as in cats) is a time series object
> that is much easier to work with than existing classes such as ts, xts
> and others.

> ... I hope tsibbles will become the standard for handling temporal data in R (including multivariate time series, panel data, ets). I’ve been using them for about a year, and I’m still amazed at how much easier it is to do things than using other structures.